# Not able to use str() function correctly but answer is correct

Tags: python

```
def convert_distanc[e(miles):][1]
    return (miles * 1.6),((miles*1.6)*2)  # approximately 1.6 km in 1 mile
distance,double_distance = convert_distance(55)
print("The distance in Kilometers is: "+ str(distance))
print("The round-trip in Kilometers is: "+ str(double_distance))
```

Not quite. Remember to use the str() function to convert
numbers into strings when printing them with text, and 
call the function with just one parameter, then accept the
return value into a new variable.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, your question is not clear. You seem to have just given us a snippet of code, and your teacher's comments about the code. What is your actual question?

Comment: Are you asking about why the ".0" occurs?

Comment: modify your post so that we can better understand your question